# What actually happens when I run "cli; hlt" on my Linux system?

Tags: linux, assembly

So I recently figured out that there's a `HLT` opcode for halting the CPU. Cool, let's see what happens!

```
user@box:~$ cat > test.c
int main(void)
{
    __asm__("HLT");
    return 0;
}
user@box:~$ gcc -o test test.c
user@box:~$ ./test
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
user@box:~$
```

Duh! How boring.

Turns out `HLT` is a privileged instruction, so let's try something else.

```
user@box:~$ mkdir test; cd test
user@box:~/test$ cat > test.c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

int init_module(void)
{
    __asm__("hlt");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
}
user@box:~/test$ echo obj-m += test.o > Makefile
user@box:~/test$ make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build modules M=$(pwd)
[...]
user@box:~/test$ sudo insmod test.ko
user@box:~/test$
```

Nothing happens! Boring!

As it turns out, `HLT` halts the CPU... until the next interrupt. Cool, so let's try disabling interrupts. `CLI` sounds like it'll do what we want.

```
user@box:~/test$ sudo rmmod test
user@box:~/test$ sed -i 's/hlt/cli; hlt/' test.c
user@box:~/test$ make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build modules M=$(pwd)
[...]
user@box:~/test$ sudo insmod test.ko
```

...and at this point, the OS stopped responding to my input. I couldn't move the cursor, or type anything using my keyboard. Pretty much frozen.

Except it wasn't. The clock in my GUI's panel kept on running. Hell, even the music kept on playing. It was as if only my mouse and my keyboard had stopped working. I realized that my (USB) keyboard didn't have power any more, not even my caps lock LED would work.

So, what happened here? Why does a pair of instructions that I feel like should "hang up" the system only shut down my USB devices? Why does everything else keep on running? As a bonus: What do I have to do to actually make the system freeze?

Comment: What kind of system is this?  `CLI` only applies to the CPU it's running on, so if you have multiple CPUs you would have to run it on each one.  Anything not relying on the `CLI+HLT` CPU would be free to continue on its merry way

Comment: I tested it on my normal desktop machine running on one CPU with multiple cores. I know that each core is also one "logical" CPU; is that what you're referring to?

Answer (score 3):

Halting the CPU does not completely halt the processor. It's usually executed by the operating system when there is no more work to be done. The CPU then enters an IDLE state from which it can wake-up anytime for example by an interrupt, but also by ACPI - so you might want to try to stop that as well: In your BIOS or as a boot argument:

> acpi=off

The reason for USB devices to not work anymore was due to the disabled interrupts although according to [this discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125539/is-usb-uhci-polling-based-or-interrupt-driven) USB is not interrupt driven by design.

For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings